# what's the difference between kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh and auto.leader.rebalance.enable?

Tags: apache-kafka

After restart brokers, I found all partitions in one topic's leader were
 all in broker 3, and I have set
  `imbalance.check.interval.seconds` 300, `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` True
but after 300 seconds nothing happened.

So I used `bin/kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh`, and got what I expected,
 the leaders were balanced into brokers 1, 2, 3.

I wonder why auto rebalance not happened? What's the difference between `kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh` and `auto.leader.rebalance.enable`?

the controller log:

> [2019-08-14 09:31:33,454] INFO [Controller id=3] Processing automatic
>   preferred replica leader election (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
>   [2019-08-14 09:31:33,454] TRACE [Controller id=3] Checking need to
>   trigger auto leader balancing (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
>   [2019-08-14 09:31:33,455] DEBUG [Controller id=3] Preferred replicas
>   by broker Map(2 -> Map(__consumer_offsets-22 -> Vector(2),
>   __consumer_offsets-4 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-7 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-46 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-25 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-49 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-16
>   -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-28 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-31 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-37 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-19 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-13
>   -> Vector(2), fourth_topic-1 -> Vector(2, 3, 1), __consumer_offsets-43 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-1 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-34 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-10 -> Vector(2), __consumer_offsets-40 -> Vector(2)), 1 -> Map(__consumer_offsets-30 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-21 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-27
>   -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-9 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-33 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-36 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-42 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-3 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-18 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-15 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-24 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-48
>   -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-6 -> Vector(1), fourth_topic-0 -> Vector(1, 2, 3), __consumer_offsets-0 -> Vector(1),
>   __consumer_offsets-39 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-12 -> Vector(1), __consumer_offsets-45 -> Vector(1)), 3 ->
>   Map(__consumer_offsets-8 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-35 ->
>   Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-41 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-23
>   -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-47 -> Vector(3), fourth_topic-2 -> Vector(3, 1, 2), __consumer_offsets-38 -> Vector(3),
>   __consumer_offsets-17 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-11 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-2 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-14 ->
>   Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-20 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-44
>   -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-5 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-26 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-29 -> Vector(3), __consumer_offsets-32 -> Vector(3))) (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-08-14 09:31:33,455] DEBUG
>   [Controller id=3] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 2
>   Map(fourth_topic-1 -> Vector(2, 3, 1))
>   (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-08-14 09:31:33,455] DEBUG
>   [Controller id=3] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 2
>   Map(fourth_topic-1 -> Vector(2, 3, 1))
>   (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-08-14 09:31:33,456] TRACE
>   [Controller id=3] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 2 is
>   0.05555555555555555 (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-08-14 09:31:33,456] DEBUG [Controller id=3] Topics not in preferred replica
>   for broker 1 Map(fourth_topic-0 -> Vector(1, 2, 3))
>   (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-08-14 09:31:33,456] TRACE
>   [Controller id=3] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 1 is
>   0.05555555555555555 (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-08-14 09:31:33,456] DEBUG [Controller id=3] Topics not in preferred replica
>   for broker 3 Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-08-14
>   09:31:33,456] TRACE [Controller id=3] Leader imbalance ratio for
>   broker 3 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

but leaders of fourth_topic's partitions are still all in broker 3:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.xx.xx.xx:2181/kafka  --topic fourth_topic --describe
Topic:fourth_topic      PartitionCount:3        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: fourth_topic     Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,1,2
        Topic: fourth_topic     Partition: 1    Leader: 3       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,1,2
        Topic: fourth_topic     Partition: 2    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 3,1,2
```

Comment: Anything in the controller logs?

Comment: add controller log, any help ?

Comment: Oh I see,since the imbalance ratio is not high enough,thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When running `kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh`, it forces the election of the preferred replica for all partitions.

On the other hand, when you set `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` to true, the Controller will regularly check the imbalance (every `leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds`). However, to avoid unnecessary load on the cluster, leaders are only automatically rebalanced if the imbalance ratio is above `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage` which defaults to 10%.

You can see the current imbalance ratio in the controller log (by default: `${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log`).